# Solr: Wildcard search for hypenated words fails

Tags: solr

I want to store documents which contain fields with hyphens, and search on these fields with wildcard search.

I'm using the default queryparser.

At both index/query time, hyphenated words are parsed by the

```
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
```

resulting in the dash being used as a delimiter.

This seems to work fine, except when combined with a wildcard in one search field.

street_nl:st AND street_nl:stevensstra*  WILL find a document with "st-stevensstraat" as field
street_nl:st-stevensstra* WILL NOT find anything. I assume this is translated to a phrase query (in which the wildcard does not work) rather than a multiple terms search

What am I doing wrong?